# how to search and print db in wordpress?

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress

I'm having difficulty in developing a functionality because I am a beginner in both WordPress and Web

I am trying to implement a search functionality.

When the user enters a value using search bar, the result is found in the DB and printed.

I know how to make a search bar.
like this.

```
<form> <input id="search" placeholder="Search...">
<input type="button" value="search"></form>
```

and also i know found value sql query...

```
$sql = "EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM 'bitnami_wordpress' . 'wp_postmeta' WHERE (CONVERT('meta_value' USING utf8) LIKE '%searchkeyword%')
```

but i don't know how do i receives the value to %searchkeyword% from entered in search bar

and I don't know how to print out the results.

i want to bring 'meta_id' of 'meta_value' that matches '%searchkeyword%'

Please.. Please help me write the code.
I can't even begin because i don't have knowledge...
Please...

Answer (score 1):

I would start by referencing the [codex for wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) and all the goodies that go with it. That will help save a lot of headache over writing a query from scratch.

Also what might be a better approach is to run a meta_query using the [WP_Query class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) which is quite similar.

Both of these methods are demonstrated [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144078/get-posts-by-meta-value).

Once you print_r the results from the queries and get to know the results you can start to form a proper loop.